# Why can't  I mount a swap partition?

Tags: fstab, swap

When I try to `sudo swapon -a` i get this message:

```
swapon: /dev/sdb4: read swap header failed: Invalid argument
```

`sdb4` is where my swap partition is.

`sudo blkid` gives back this:

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="75622b47-3265-48a6-a697-265b44bdfe55" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="d638620e-b8b1-49ae-b234-7e89aa0de676" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="E656-2CAB" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="83e2e318-eee6-4864-a1c4-330bd16bc6a7" TYPE="swap"
```

this is the content of `fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=75622b47-3265-48a6-a697-265b44bdfe55 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
#UUID=86d7eebb-b840-4fb0-a1fc-a84074062cb2 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0   
/dev/sdb4        none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 6):

**Check if swap partition is set up correctly**

Execute the command `sudo fdisk -l`. This will list all your partitions and their partition types.  In Ubuntu, a swap partition will be listed similar to below:

```
/dev/sdb4            7295        8268     7811072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

If you don't see the last 2 values `82` and `Linux Swap`, then it is not setup as swap partition.

**Setup a swap partition**

Ensure that the partition you are going to use (such as /dev/sdb4) is not a real partition with real data before turning it in to swap partition since all your data will be lost.

The following steps will set up a swap partition:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Replace /dev/sdb4 with the correct partition name if different:

```
sudo /sbin/mkswap /dev/sdb4
```

Enable the swap partition you just set up:

```
sudo swapon -a
```

For detailed help, refer to 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Answer (score 5):

Simple: you don't have an sdb4 partition!  Your swap appears to be on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  It looks like you setup cryptswap, so you need to fix your fstab to point to the new swap partition, preferably by UUID, not by device name.

Comment: Kudos to psusi for reading more closely than I did.  My answer completely misses the point...